# Is my WCF service secure?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm using wsHttpBinding but my config contains:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
              <wsHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="MyBinding">
                          <security mode="None" />
                    </binding>
              </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Does the `security mode="None"` mean that the security is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, security mode `None` will disable the security mechanism for that binding. Try to avoid using `None`, use either `Transport` (HTTPS + SSL Certificates) or `Message` (security directly by SOAP structure), as for using `none` might give birth to heavy security issues.